# Simple Python Web-scraper with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape car data. Their 'id' tags increment by 1, however i just can't seem to figure out how to do that. Here is what I have:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib

source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.25thstauto.com/inventory.aspx?cursort=asc&pagesize=500').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

#finds the total number of cars
count = soup.find('span', {'id': 'ctl00_cphBody_inv1_lblVehicleCount'}).getText()[:2]
count = int(count)

i = 1
for url in range(1,count):
url = soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'ctl00_cphBody_inv1_rptInventoryNew_ctl0'+i+'_nlVehicleDetailsTitle'})
    print(url['href'])
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: I do not know why this question is downvoted, I upvoted for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
import re

source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.25thstauto.com/inventory.aspx?cursort=asc&pagesize=500').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for a in soup.find_all('a', id=re.compile('ctl00_cphBody_inv1_rptInventoryNew')):
    print(a.get('href'))
```

out:

```
2008_Chevrolet_Malibu_Easton_PA_265928462.veh
2008_Chevrolet_Malibu_Easton_PA_265928462.veh
2008_Chevrolet_Malibu_Easton_PA_265928462.veh
2002_Nissan_Xterra_Easton_PA_266894015.veh
2002_Nissan_Xterra_Easton_PA_266894015.veh
2002_Nissan_Xterra_Easton_PA_266894015.veh
2009_Chevrolet_Cobalt_Easton_PA_265621796.veh
2009_Chevrolet_Cobalt_Easton_PA_265621796.veh
```

Use [regex](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to find `a` tag whose `id` attribute contain `ctl00_cphBody_inv1_rptInventoryNew`

OR use [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for a in soup.select('a[id*=ctl00_cphBody_inv1_rptInventoryNew]'):
    print(a.get('href'))
```

The idea is same.

Comment: you are a god among peasants in the stackoverflow kingdom

Comment: @Sean Kelly ignore the downvote, I think there is someone downvote everything. If you have any question like this, welcome to tag at `beautifulsoup` and I will be there for you.

Comment: Thank you friend. Stay tuned, because I may have more!